# Webpack 3: css-loader style-loader error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-3

**I am receiving the following error:**

> ERROR in ./common/app.css Module parse failed:
>   E:\universal-starter\common\app.css Unexpected token (1:5) You may
>   need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

```
| body {
|     background-color: orange;
| }
```

**My App.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';
require('./app.css');

const App = () => <div>Hello from React</div>;

export default App;
```

**My webpack.config:**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextWebpackPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './client/index',
  ],
  target: 'web',
```

---

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        options: {
          emitWarning: true
        },
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        test: /\.js?$/,
        use: ['babel-loader']},
```

// WHY IS THIS WRONG & CAUSING THE PROBLEM?!?!?!?!

```
      // embed styles in styles folder
      {

        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextWebpackPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: ['css-loader']
        })
      },
```

---

```
      // fonts
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=1024&name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
      },
      // examine img file size
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 40000,
            name: 'images/[name].[hash].[ext]',
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        }
        ]
      }
    ],
  },
```

---

```
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextWebpackPlugin('./css/styles.css'),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: './client/template/index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': { BUILD_TARGET: JSON.stringify('client') },
    }),
  ],
```

---

```
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3001,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.build'),
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3001/',
    filename: 'client.js',
  },
};
```

**Very little help out there so far on Webpack 3. 
Any ideas?
Thanks!!**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
In your App.js file, replace `require('./app.css');` for `import './app.css'`